# Show script if wordpress postid is even and GTM

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add InRead Ads via GTM with this logic:

```js
<script>
  
function set_ad_player(){
var el = document.querySelector('section[data-postid]');
 var idp = el.getAttribute('data-postid');

    
   if (idp%2 == 0) {
    window._ttf = window._ttf || [];
    _ttf.push({
        pid          : 0202020
        ,lang        : "es"
        ,slot        : '.entry-content > p'
        ,minSlot     : 4,
        format       : "inread"
        ,components  : { mute: {delay: 6}, skip: {delay :6} }
        ,css         : "margin: 27px 0px 28px;padding: 0px 9px;"
    });

    (function (d) {
        var js, s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.async = true;
        js.src = '//cdn.teads.tv/media/format.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(js, s);
    })(window.document);

 console.log(idp);
   } else{
    (function() {
      window["SMIntextSetUp"] = {
        c:'.entry-content > p',
        adPosition:4,
        viewable_desktop:true,
        viewable_mobile:true,
        adSkip:true,
    restart:true,
        tag_desktop:'https%3A%2F%2Fvod.addevweb.com%2Fsunmedia%2Fdemos%2Ftags%2Fnormal.xml',
        tag_mobile:'https%3A%2F%2Fvod.addevweb.com%2Fsunmedia%2Fdemos%2Ftags%2Fnormal.xml'
      };
      var a,t,s,n;
      t = document.createElement("script");
      t.async = true;
      t.onerror=function(){if(SMIntextSetUp.passback!=null)window[SMIntextSetUp.passback]();};
      t.type = "text/javascript";
      s="https:" == document.location.protocol;
      t.src = (s ? "https:" : "http:") + "//static.addevweb.com/SMOutstream/SMIntext/SMIntext.js";
      n = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      n.parentNode.insertBefore(t, n);
    })();
  }
  
  }


  set_ad_player()


</script>
```

My Logic es based in getting the Wordpress postID via Javascript and then passing the attribute to the conditional that will determine if the postid number is Even or is Odd.

Google Tag Manager will fire this in every single of Wordpress.

My question is related if the condition is correct and if this code must be triggered in DomReady or WindowLoad.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if SO is a good place for code review. You can trigger your code at DOM ready (since by this time the DOM elements will be available for querying).  GTM has a built in selector engine, so instead of doing document.querySelector your can use a DOM type variable and set the "attribute" field to the data attribute to return its value. Also Google recommends against using tags that change page layout from within GTM (that does not mean it won't work, but GTM is async and you may experience flickers or repaints if you insert ads in the finished DOM).

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not correct. You should cast string to integer

```
.....
var idp = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-postid'));    
if (idp%2 == 0) {
.....
```

And you should call your code after domready. SHould be like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    //use your code here
})();
</script>
```